# UITableView contentOffset resets after UIScrollView scrolls

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView which I want to be above my tableView. I put it as a subview of my tableview - when it is added the tableview is scrolled down to the relavent section using the tableView's contentOffset. When the scrollview is scrolled the tableView scrolls back up to the top.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: If you want the scrollview to be above the tableview, why are you making the scrollview a subview of the tableview? You should make the scrollview and the tableview both be subviews of a common parent view.

Comment: I am using a UITableViewController so I have no choice I think?

Comment: Then user a `UIViewController` instead and add the scrollview and tableview as subviews.

Answer (score 0):

You must add instance of  UIScrollView as subview of tableView cell. 
E.g.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 30;}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.row == 15) {
    return 200;
}
return 44; }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (indexPath.row == 15) {

    UIScrollView *scroll = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)] autorelease];
    scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 500);
    [cell addSubview:scroll];
}


return cell; }
```

Then you can set tableView's contentOffset in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 400); }
```

Also you can create custom cell with scrollView by subclassing UITableViewCell. Lear how to 
customize tableView cells in this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/).

Comment: I am trying to get the UIScrollView completely above the table, but not alter the offset of the tableView when it is scrolled. I am using a tableViewController so I added it to my tableView. I may not have explained this clearly enough in my initial question. I'll edit it now.